# I need a nice video game for my daughter

Tags: game

It needs to utilize the 7 channel headphone logitech I bought for her. It's artemis G633. Also I gave her i7 computer with 16 GB memory and gtx 1060 video card. Far more than enough to play overwatch with 60 hz at full HD 1920-1080 and record the game with OBS. So she can be a pro you tube gamer early in life.

I tried overwatch. But my estranged wife says it's full with violent and doesn't allow her.

I tried skyrim.

That way she learn modding games and can learn searching stuff in internet. I think it's far more useful than what schools taught.

I tried warcraft but she said she doesn't like it.

It needs to be the best games. Something like award winning.

I was disappointed that my wife told her to play farm ville. I want the best for my daugther. What game I should buy for her?

Comment: don't just downvote. answer. give me one non violent awesome games that take advantage of graphics

Comment: Are you sure this is the right place for this question? wouldn't Parenting or maybe Aqrade be better places for this type of question?

Comment: Maybe Portal/Portal 2, it has minimal violence, you can't kill anything.  You do drop your companion cube into a fire, and there are a few turrets which fire at you, but you have a portal gun.  It shoot portals, not bullets.

Comment: what kind of violence is too much?  Is there a distinction between violence required, and violence by choice.  In many FPS, you have to kill to continue, but in stealth games like thief 4, and 3 deadly shadows you can complete the game by only knocking people unconscious.  Although, I have never tried it some claim to have, with much skill and time, said they completed it without even doing that.  In this type of game you can kill, but you don't because it is the easy non-stealth way out.

Comment: @chillie I ask you to recommend me a software. And you think this is not the place? After all what do people in parenting knows about games?

Comment: That being said, @chillie is right. I will ask in both forum.

Comment: "what do people in parenting knows about games?" - is your wife active here? Is she a parent?   Btw, it might help is you could give your daughter's age and more of your wife's rules (or is the only rule "no violence"?). Or, ask your wife to help choose.  Btw, i7 sounds like overkill for a child, unless you are serious about " be a pro you tube gamer early in life", in which case, you should probably discuss ***that*** on Parenting.

Comment: @JimThio Well, I am a parent, and I know a bit. I would assume any good parent would want to know what there child is playing, watching or listening to. You're asking a question about your daughter and comes off as "what games are suitable for kids". Sounds like a Parenting question or a gaming question don't you think? Asking what to people in Parenting know about games, is like asking what do any of us know about any of the questions we give responds to. I'm not the one who down voted your question, but that doesn't mean I believe this is the right spot for it.

Answer (score 1):

I can personally think of a couple of games, but you seem to infer two requirements that, in my experience, often contradict. As such, I will address the inferred requirements, before I recommend some games.

### Requirements

#### Utilising the hardware

You report an i7 processor, with 16GB of RAM and a decent graphic card. You also report a 7 channel headphone. This is a fairly decent setup; but I must point out that, in most part, you will not be utilising the full extent of such a rig. I personally study in video game development, and even the programs designed to *create* games rarely require more than 8GB of RAM. It certainly might help, along side other applications; especially if your daughter intends to stream, at some point.

In regards to the headphones, all games are going to be able to utilise this device. However, as far as I am aware, a 7 channel headphone is quite uncommon. I feel I should add the disclaimer that, in most circumstances, you will be utilising the 7 channel headphone as a higher-quality 2 channel headphone. That is, many games will not specifically split the audio into 7 separate channels; you might notice a higher level of audio quality, but you will likely also only notice a left and right channel.

#### "No Violence"

It is important to address the fact that *"Overwatch"* is a game that is rated for *teenagers*. That means that the [entertainment software recommendation board](http://www.esrb.org/) have reviewed the entirety of the content provided in said game, and decided that it is not a particularly violent game; it is officially suitable for anyone over the age of 13.

In contrast, *"The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim"* has a rating of M15+. It is considerably more violent, including graphical "fatalities" and blood. In my opinion, disallowing *"Overwatch"* for its violence while allowing *"The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim"* is a contradiction. It is entirely possible that your ex-wife is simply unaware of the content in the later game, and would otherwise disallow this game, too.

I make note of this, as this greatly restricts the selection of games that are available. Instead of looking for games with a "T" rating, we have to look for games that offer "no violence"; but the definition of "no violence" is quite broad, in this context. As such, I will recommend games that *could* be considered "violent", with a short explanation of the included violence. This way, you can make your own mind up, and discuss said games with your ex-wife.

### Recommendations

#### [Terraria](http://store.steampowered.com/app/105600/Terraria/)

[image]

Terraria is constructive 2D platformer, and could easily be described as "Minecraft meets Super Mario". The game is easy to learn, but hard to master; and involves as much crafting and construction as platforming and monster fighting. It is a great game for kids and parents, alike; you could easily find yourself playing this game with your daughter.

The game features cartoon violence, as the player must fight off a variety of monsters, using a variety of weapons. On research, it appears Terraria has not actually won any awards; but this surprises me. The game has an "Overwhelmingly Positive" score, on Steam, and has sold millions and millions of copies. They also still release free updates.

- **Developer:** Re-Logic
- **Genre:** Action Adventure RPG
- **Release Date:** May, 2011
- **Rating:** T
- [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7uOhFTrrq0)

#### [Fallout 4](http://store.steampowered.com/app/377160/Fallout_4/)

[image]

I only mention Fallout 4 due to your mention of Skyrim. Fallout is a post-apocalyptic RPG, where the main character escapes from a "vault" following all-out nuclear war. The game involves construction and considerable RPG elements, and was built with a newer<sup>1</sup> version of the engine used to build Skyrim.

The game includes considerable violence, and as such, is rated M. Again, this is not dissimilar to Skyrim, though there is a greater emphasis on stylised "fatalities". The game has been nominated for and won a considerable number of awards, including "Most Wanted Game" from the 33rd Golden Joystick Awards, and the "People's Choice" "Game of the Year 2015" award.

- **Developer:** Bethesda
- **Genre:** RPG
- **Release Date:** November, 2015
- **Rating:** M
- [Trailer](https://youtu.be/GE2BkLqMef4)

<sub><sup>1</sup> Of course, they re-released Skyrim, using the upgraded engine they used for Fallout 4. If your daughter played Skyrim: Definitive Edition, she would already be familiar with this engine. If not, she would be familiar with its predecessor.</sub>

#### [World of Warcraft: Legion](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/legion/)

[image]

You say that World of Warcraft did not fly, but given the other titles, I wonder if your daughter would have a differant opinion of the latest expansion. Having played World of Warcraft between the first and third expansions, and having only come back as of Legion, I can personally attest to the fact that it is a different game. As soon as you hit the "Legion" content, the game progresses into a more story-driven, cinematic experience. It is worth noting that purchasing the expansion gives you the ability to instantly roll one character as a "level 100" - the level required to experience the new content. Having a character of this level also permits you to create a "Demon Hunter" of the same level, which in turn, is also a new and entertaining experience.

Once again, you have some degree of violence, given the nature of the game. However, it has only been rated T for Teens, by the ESRB. That said, so was Overwatch. Game Informer awarded this game awards for "Best PC Exclusive" and "Best MMO", and I have heard veteran players refer to it as "the best expansion Blizzard ever created". I would personally recommend watching some of the introduction videos, with your daughter, to truly gauge her opinion.

- **Developer:** Blizzard
- **Genre:** MMORPG
- **Release Date:** August, 2016
- **Rating:** T
- [Trailer](https://youtu.be/2bwg0YBP_H4)

#### [Portal](http://store.steampowered.com/app/400/Portal/)

[image]

Portal is a simple game that was met with a massive critical reception. The player wakes up in a science lab, and is told that they must effectivley perform as a "lab rat" to make it through. The player must navigate a series of puzzles, utilising the "portal gun"; a gun that shoots linked portals. Jump through the blue portal, and you will appear out of the orange portal. Seems simple, but the physics and general style of the game has made this one for the ages. It is fairly short, in comparison with other games; if your daughter enjoys it, I might recommend checking out the sequel.

The game is rated T, and mostly involves references to violence, rather than actual violence. There are turrets that shoot at you, but in contrast with many other games, they are also known to say "I love you". [The game has won a considerable amount of awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_(video_game)#Awards), including making it onto Times list of greatest video games of all time, and has even spawned a meme through its own popularity. If you have ever heard someone say "the cake is a lie", you can thank Portal.

- **Developer:** Valve
- **Genre:** Puzzle
- **Release Date:** October, 2007
- **Rating:** T
- [Trailer](https://youtu.be/TluRVBhmf8w)

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit troubled here. You gave the specs of the computer, but **you have not provided the specs of your daughter**, mainly her age, and taste.

You need to categorize the type of games there are.

Something like:

- 1st person shooter
- Role playing (3th person)
- Massively multiplayer online game
- Construction games
- Racing...

Etc.

Take a look at this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_game_genres

**The final spec would be. What does she like to play?** What if she wants to construct awesome things in Minecraft?

---

> OBS. So she can be a pro you tube gamer early in life.

Ok First check if OBS is the best option. Take a look at other programs like Bandicam.

---

P.S.1. A pro-YouTuber probably additionally need to learn how to edit, what to say, how to interact with the network. Etc. But that is another topic.

P.S.2. Probably a game could be learning how to make games. Learning a 3D modeling program, Blender perhaphs? or a 3D game engine like the Unreal engine? That could be an interesting thing to learn early in life.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I certainly upvoted it :-)